# Does Google Autobackup application, checks for duplicate before uploading, considering renamed files?

Tags: google-plus-photos

I have photos within iPhoto, which were also exported once and renamed to a Desktop folder. The photos in iPhoto should have already been uploaded to Google Plus Photos, but I will still like to point the Google Autobackup preferences to the Desktop folder which contains exports of photos (renamed) along with other photos that weren't in iPhoto.

So, will Google Autobackup upload a duplicate of the photo due to a file renaming?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately answer appears to be yes based on my test. Google Autobackup will upload a duplicate.

Update: Although I see an upload count that appears it duplicated but in the web I only see one instance of the photo.

Comment: The issue I am having, is that Google Autobackup is generating a warning that my account doesn't have enough space to process the folder/photos, so I can't run a test to see if it will duplicate my photos upload.